# Overide inline font face?

Tags: css, inline-styles

Im importing an XML feed which has inline styles applied to its divs like:

```
 face="Verdana"
```

I want to override this with CSS. Ive tried this:

```
#containing-div div {  
    font-family: arial !important; 
}
```

But its not working. As 'face' is deprecated I'd hoped it would be overridden with the 'font-family' but it appears not to be. Given that I can't change the XML feed (I know I should be able to but just trust me!), how can I override this?
Thanks

Comment: If you have an URL, where we can see this live, the diagnosis would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this:

```
face="Verdana"
```

is actually this:

```
<font face="Verdana">..</font>
```

*(and it must be, right? There's no way it's `<div face="">`)*

then you should use this CSS:

```
#containing-div, #containing-div font {  
    font-family: arial; 
}
```

There should be no need for `!important`. The point is to select the `font` elements.

Comment: Great. Ive used font-family: Inherit; which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the "XML" part. Can you set other properties with the `#containing-div div` selector, like background or border? If not, the selector might not match, because the ID is not correctly defined by the XML fragment or the namespaces don't match.

Comment: Its not that, I am able to control other things with CSS. Thanks